# How to transfer data from WD Hard Drive to Computer using Sabrent

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, windows-xp, usb, external-hard-drive

I had very old computer that stopped working(don't really know the reason). Got(detached) hard drive from it and wanted to open it on my new computer as an external hard drive. I bought Sabrent USB-DSC9 and uses SATA cable to connect to my computer. It discovers it but when you double click on it explorer path will start loading greenish bar and stays there for a while:

[image]

Then it gives me this error:

[image]

Well, now I am assuming that my hard drive is corrupted. The question is there anything I can use to recover data from it? It had very important docs for me. Maybe some software? Anything that can help. Thank you.

PS: My OS is Windows 10. Hard Drive: 1TB SATA - 64 MB cache(was on Windows XP)

Answer (score 0):

Run HDTune and see if you can access it. Check the SMART status tab and that will give you some clues about possible damage, then run a full scan to see if there are bad blocks. If you find bad blocks, run HDD regenerator to try to repair them.

If you can't access the drive at all with HDTune, try HDD regenerator from start.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds pretty unfortunate, @Zhaiyk! I'm sorry to hear about your issues with this 1 TB WD HDD of yours. I'd recommend you check how the HDD would get recognized if you connect it internally via SATA, instead of the SATA-to-USB connector. I'd also advise you to go to [Disk Management in Windows](http://support.wdc.com/KnowledgeBase/answer.aspx?ID=1284) and check how the hard drive is recognized there. Posting some more screenshots would be helpful, too.

Just like Overmind mentioned, it's  highly recommended to run the diagnostic tests on the drive, either from the utility mentioned above or our brand-specific tool [WD's Data LifeGuard Diagnostics for Windows](http://support.wdc.com/downloads.aspx?lang=en). Running the QUICK & EXTENDED tests from there could also help you determine the health & SMART status.

Keep us posted with the results & troubleshooting!
Good luck!